# How to display a large amount of data using Mongoose, Mean, Express, and Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

**EDIT**
I tried limiting my results and it appears that I can get 100 or so results without any problem but anything more than that nothing displays.  Is there a way to stream the data so that it just displays it it's received?  I thought that was one of Node's strong points

**Original** I have an app using Node, Mongoose, Express, and Angular.  I'm trying to send my data from my mongo app to be displayed with angular.  When I use a query to find one result, the app works fine. However, when I try to send back the data nothing shows up.  Here is my code:

**app/models/org.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Org', new Schema({
    ein : {type : Number},
}), 'irs9902013');
```

**app/routes.js**

```
var Org  = require('./models/org');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/api/orgs', function(req, res){
        Org.find({}, {"EIN" : 1, _id : 0}, function(err, doc){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(doc);
        });

    });
};
```

**public/js/controllers/OrgCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('OrgCtrl', []).controller('OrgController', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('/api/orgs')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.orgs = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
});
```

**public/js/services/OrgService.js**

```
angular.module('OrgService', []).factory('Org', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/orgs');
        },
    }       
}]);
```

**public/views/org.html**

```
<div ng-controller="OrgController" ng-repeat="org in orgs">
    {{ org.EIN }}
</div>
```

My server runs fine (I can include the code for that if you think it'd be helpful) and my view is wrapped in another file that includes the correct ng-app name.  I'm not getting any errors but it does not seem to be working.  It might also be worth noting that there are over 200,000 records that are supposed to be returned.

Comment: if you console log doc, does anything show up? also whats the purpose for passing an empty object as the first argument of the mongoose find function? If you want all the records returned wouldnt you just do Org.find(function(err, docs){ ... });

Comment: Console log doc brings up everything I'm trying to get.  The first argument is query your criteria and the second argument is only return the selected field from the results rather than all of the fields...

Comment: Btw why do you have service name Org in OrgService module and are still accessing the server directly in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

edit this

public/views/org.html

```
<div ng-controller="OrgController" ng-repeat="org in orgs">
    {{ org.ein }}
</div>
```